# simulated GPS covariance and robot_pose_ekf

Tags: navigation, simulation, ekf, gps, robot-pose-ekf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I try to add a GPS in simulation of a Husky robot, but the covariance is set to zero by default (for simulated GPS) so the robot_pose_ekf didn't run. I set it manually to 99999.0 like in [utm_odometry_node](http://wiki.ros.org/gps_common) , and the robot_pose_ekf subscribes to the topic, but it doesn't publish the odom_combined frame. No error appears in the terminal.
Any idea?

Here are part of my code :

```
<node name="gps_conv" pkg="gps_common" type="utm_odometry_node">
    <remap from="odom" to="vo"/>
    <remap from="fix" to="/gps/fix" />
    <param name="rot_covariance" value="99999" />
</node>
    
<node pkg="robot_pose_ekf" type="robot_pose_ekf" name="robot_pose_ekf" output="screen">
    <rosparam command="load" file="$(find moveit_simulation)/config/husky_ekf.yaml"/>
    <remap from="imu_data" to="imu/data"/>
    <remap from="odom" to="odom_pub"/>
</node>
```

and here are the ekf parameters :

```
freq: 30.0
output_frame: "odom_combined"
sensor_timeout: 1.0
publish_tf: true
odom_used: true
imu_used: true
gps_used: true
imu_absolute: true
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197860/simulated-gps-covariance-and-robot_pose_ekf/) by [est_CEAR](https://answers.ros.org/users/20539/est_cear/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2014-11-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
It seems to be a problem from simulation, because I didn't get it on the real robot with real GPS

---

Originally posted by [est_CEAR](https://answers.ros.org/users/20539/est_cear/) with karma: 170 on 2015-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0